# Spamming submit button to import CSV file

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, submit, webix

I have a little problem haha let me explain :
I need to import a CSV file. Then I need to parse this file to convert him in a JSON object to call an api to update my database.

It works fine but the problem is : I have to spam my upload button to upload this file and I don't know why. This one works only once in 20.

This is my code :

Test.html

```
<!-- Select file CSV -->
<div class="file-field input-field">
    <div class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light green">
        <span>File</span>
        <input type="file" id="fileUpload">
    </div>
    
    <!-- Get the name of the file -->
    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
        <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Import the file -->
<div class="file-field input-field">
    <div class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light green">
        <span>Upload</span>
        <input type="button" id="upload" onclick="upload()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Test.js

```
function upload(){
var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv)$/;
        if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    //console.log("Raw File");
                    //console.log(e.target.result);
                    var lines=e.target.result.split('\r');
                    for(let i = 0; i<lines.length-1; i++){ 
                        lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/\s/,'')//delete all blanks
                    }
                    var result = [];

                    var headers=lines[0].split(",");

                    for(var i=1;i<lines.length-1;i++){ 
                        var obj = {};
                        var currentline=lines[i].split(",");

                        for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
                            obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
                        }
                        result.push(obj);
                    }
                    //console.log("After JSON Conversion");
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

                    for(let j = 0; j<result.length; j++){
                        objToUpdate = {};
                        objToUpdate.objRotation = parseInt(result[j].OBJ_ROTATION,10);
                        objToUpdate.objStock = parseInt(result[j].OBJ_STOCK,10);
                        objToUpdate.codeEns = parseInt(result[j].CD_MAG,10);
                        objToUpdate.codeDep = parseInt(result[j].CD_DEP,10);
                        objToUpdate.codeRay = parseInt(result[j].CD_RAY,10);
                        console.log(objToUpdate);
                        $.ajax({
                            type : "PUT",
                            url : "api/test?type=update",
                            data : JSON.stringify(objToUpdate),
                            success : function(obj){
                                webix.message("Ligne mise à jour");
                            }
                        });
                        
                    } 
                }
                reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        } else {
           console.log("Pas ok regex CSV");
        }
```

}

I just don't know where is the problem and why I have to spam this button to upload the file.
I would have understood if the button was not working but he works sometimes.

Thanks for advice

Comment: How large is the CSV file? (how many lines?). I'm not 100% sure, but since you're looping over every line 3 times to perform your operations, maybe the UI is frozen while it's processing the file? Try with a smaller one

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.
I don't think the problem is the CSV file. I have only 2 lines on this CSV file for testing.

Comment: I tried to change my function upload(); 

Like this : 

function upload(){
    console.log("test");
}

and she's called 1 times on 50 lol 
100% it's not the CSV file the problem, so I don't know why she's called sometimes and not every time

Comment: If you get the same behavior with just `console.log("test");` in your function, please remove all the code you posted in your question, and just put the code necessary to reproduce the issue (maybe all that HTML is not even needed to reproduce the issue? Just a simple button?). That will make things easier to debug

Comment: Ok I found the problem. I just remove the onClick on my input and replace on my div and delete the input. 
I didn't pay attention of my html code but my Onclick was not well placed ! 
I replace the Onclick on the Div and now it's work every time. 
All good now, thanks for your help blex !